# Questions after reading the API doc of upload session

Tags: rest, onedrive

I'm a bit confused after reading this [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/onedrive/developer/rest-api/api/driveitem_createuploadsession#upload-bytes-to-the-upload-session).

1. The doc says:
   `The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order. Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.`
   Does that mean that, for one file divided into #1~10 fragments in order, I can only upload *fragment 2* after I finish uploading *fragment 1*? If so, why is it possible to have multiple `nextExpectedRanges`? I mean, if you upload fragments one by one, you can make sure that previous fragments have already been uploaded.
2. According to the doc, byte range size has to be a multiple of 320 KB. Does that imply that the total file size has to be a multiple of 320 KB also?

Answer (score 0):

1. There are currently some limitations that necessitate this sequencing requirement, however the long-term goal is to not. As a result, the API reflects this by supporting multiple `nextExpectedRanges`, but does not currently leverage it.
2. No, multiples of 320KiB are just the ideal size. You can choose others, and you can mix them. So for you scenario you could use all 320KiB chunks, except for the last one which would be whatever size is relevant to hit the overall size of your file.

Comment: Thank you. One more question. Can I upload multiple files at the same time? For example, use multiple threads to create multiple uploadsessions.

Comment: Yes that should be fine, but I'd still keep the number of threads low to ensure you don't oversaturate your network.